# Is there a difference Ember getJSON if I am using Swagger JS?

Tags: ember.js, swagger

to pull a JSON into a model from an API, I would normally do this:

`return Ember.$.getJSON('http://....');`

However is there a difference in syntax if I am using Swagger?

I just got introduced to this the other day at work.  The back-end developers are starting to use it... but this is new to all of us so I don't know how to utilize this on the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Swagger at all, but you can always use a promise and hook up the results that way.

Assuming the swagger connection

```
  swagger = new SwaggerApi({
    url: "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs",
    success: function() {
      if(swagger.ready === true) {
        // upon connect, fetch a pet and set contents to element "mydata"

      }
    }
  });

model: function(){
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    swagger.apis.pet.getPetById({petId:1}, function(data) {
      resolve(data.content.data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I will give it a shot.  I am assuming this can be done through the route of whichever template I will be using, yes?

Comment: would appreciate if you could also include how you've make SwaggerApi available to ember, please.